# How to remove http and https without img src

Tags: php, regex

code:

```
$str = 'http://www.google.com <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />';
$str = preg_replace('/\b(https?):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

output:

```
<img src="" />
```

i need this output:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
```

how can i do it?

thanks for help.

Comment: Use DOMDocument and DOMXPath to find all text nodes and apply your pattern to them.

Comment: Try [`/(<img.*\/>)/`](https://regex101.com/r/uT8cL1/1). So `$1` is containing what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also think that `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` are preferable tools for parsing HTML markup. 
 But just in your particular case, here is solution with regexp *negative lookbehind assertion* :

```
$str = 'http://www.google.com <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /> http://www.google.com.ua';

$str = preg_replace('/(?<!src=\")(https|http):\/\/[^\s]+\b/i', '', $str);

print_r($str);   // <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
```

This will remove all urls excepting those which are inside an `img` *src* attribute

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern

```
/\b(https?):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i
```

removes all URLs *(in the string)* which start with protocol `http` or `https`. So when you apply it on your string, it will remove both that URL which is in the beginning of the string and that URL which is as `src` of `<img>`. So you have to use `^` in the beginning of your pattern:

```
$str = 'http://www.google.com <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />';
$str = preg_replace('/^\b(https?):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/d5l0I)

---

Or simply get what you need like this:

```
/(<img.*\/>)/i
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uT8cL1/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<[^>]*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(https?):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]`

The `<[^>]*` catches all the things within an unclosed `<` and `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|` skips them.

The rest is your regex.